# How can I have access to an attribute via GET request in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, attributes, doctrine

I Symfony I try to open a page for example:

```
http://project:8888/products
```

On that page I like to show the headline with the slug:

```
<h1>{{page.slug}}</h1>
```

One problem is, that it takes really long to open the page. And the other problem is, that there is an error message, that there is no access to the attribute slug....

MyController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Pages;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Controller\DataTablesTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;


class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  /**
  * @Route("/{slug}", name="page")
  */

  use DataTablesTrait;

  public function showPage($slug)
  {
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
    $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->find($slug);
    $table = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));
    $json_string = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json');

    $file = 'data/data.json';
    file_put_contents($file, $json_string);

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['pages' => $pages, 'page' => $page]);
  }


}
```

list.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Symfony{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="wrapper">

{{ include('inc/navbar.html.twig') }}

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 866px;">

  <section class="content-header">
    <h1>{{page.slug}}</h1>

  </section>

  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body">

            <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>E-Mail</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

{% endblock %}


{% block javascripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

pages entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PagesRepository")
 */
class Pages
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $icon;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTemplate(): ?string
    {
        return $this->template;
    }

    public function setTemplate(string $template): self
    {
        $this->template = $template;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIcon(): ?string
    {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    public function setIcon(string $icon): self
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("slug") on a null variable.

[image]

Comment: what is the content of `page` ?

Comment: `$page` is null. It seems it can't find a page with the slug `products` in your database.

Comment: For the long time to open the page, you can look at `performance` in your symfony profiler to try to figure out why.

Comment: find($slug) will not work. find always looks for an id. so it will not find the page. you need findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug])

Comment: @fucethebads Please post your comment as an answer, because it is the actual solution here.

Comment: If you downvote question, can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling find($slug) will not work. Find always looks for an id, so it will not find the page. You need findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug])